# Facebook Integration Fetch All Post Data

Tags: android

I have an app page on Facebook.I want to fetch all post of my app page in my app.i know that it is possible from Facebook part api but i am not implementing that so any one can help me with proper stepping.

Answer (score 0):

This is posibble with using facebook api for android.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/
You need this instruction - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android